# C# How to convert time [ms, s, m, h, d] as string to seconds as int

Tags: c#, timespan

I would like to know if there is a quick way (Maybe with TimeSpan) to convert a duration time formatted string like `17.24s` or `20.79m` or `1.3h` to seconds format like `17` for `17.24s`, `1260` for `20.79m` and `4699` for `1.3h`.

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Can you explain better the rules to follow in this transformation? For example 1.3h becomes 4699 in base at what logic?

Comment: There are methods like `TimeSpan.FromHours/FromMinutes/FromSeconds` you can use to get a TimeSpan from a number and then access the `TotalSeconds` property. e.g. `TimeSpan.FromHours(1.3).TotalSeconds` returns 4680 (1.3 * 60 * 60). Since it returns a double and it looks like you want an integer, you can round/cast as needed for your scenario.

Comment: My fault. @Dmitry Bychenko was right with: 20.79 minutes == 20.79 * 60 seconds == 1247 seconds
    1.3 hours   == 1.3 * 3600 seconds == 4680 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions guys! I'm very appricate it. Here is my solution that workes for me:

```
    private int timeParser(string pTime) {
        int iResult = 0;
        double dTime = 0.0;
        NumberStyles style = NumberStyles.Number;
        CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        
        if(pTime.Contains("ms")) {
            if(Double.TryParse(pTime.Trim().Replace("ms", ""), style, culture, out dTime)) {
                iResult = (int)Math.Round(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(dTime).TotalSeconds);
            } else {
                throw new FormatException("Unable to convert " + pTime);
            }
        } else if(pTime.Contains("s")) {
            if(Double.TryParse(pTime.Trim().Replace("s", ""), style, culture, out dTime)) {
                iResult = (int)Math.Round(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(dTime).TotalSeconds);
            } else {
                throw new FormatException("Unable to convert " + pTime);
            }                   
        } else if(pTime.Contains("m")) {
            if(Double.TryParse(pTime.Trim().Replace("m", ""), style, culture, out dTime)) {
                iResult = (int)Math.Round(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(dTime).TotalSeconds);
            } else {
                throw new FormatException("Unable to convert " + pTime);
            }
        } else if(pTime.Contains("h")) {
            if(Double.TryParse(pTime.Trim().Replace("h", ""), style, culture, out dTime)) {
                iResult = (int)Math.Round(TimeSpan.FromHours(dTime).TotalSeconds);
            } else {
                throw new FormatException("Unable to convert " + pTime);
            }
        } else if(pTime.Contains("d")) {
            if(Double.TryParse(pTime.Trim().Replace("d", ""), style, culture, out dTime)) {
                iResult = (int)Math.Round(TimeSpan.FromDays(dTime).TotalSeconds);
            } else {
                throw new FormatException("Unable to convert " + pTime);
            }
        } else {
            throw new FormatException(pTime + " is not a valid timeformat");
        }
        return iResult;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's start from *math*:

```
  20.79 minutes == 20.79 * 60 seconds == 1247 seconds
    1.3 hours   == 1.3 * 3600 seconds == 4680 seconds
```

I can't see `1260` or `4699`, that's why I'll stick to simple math, I'll mark with `\\TODO:` the code which should be modified if you insist on different logic.

For different suffixes, let's extract model:

```
private static Dictionary<string, Func<double, TimeSpan>> s_Builders =
  new Dictionary<string, Func<double, TimeSpan>>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    
    {  "", x => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x)},
    { "s", x => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x)},
    //TODO: if you insist on 1260, put required logic here
    { "m", x => TimeSpan.FromMinutes(x)},
    //TODO: if you insist on 4699, put required logic here
    { "h", x => TimeSpan.FromHours(x)},
    { "d", x => TimeSpan.FromDays(x)},
};
```

Time to implement `TryMyParse` method:

```
public static bool TryMyParse(string value, out TimeSpan result) {
  result = default;

  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
    return false;

  string suffix = s_Builders
    .Keys
    .OrderByDescending(key => key.Length)
    .FirstOrDefault(key => value.EndsWith(key, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

  if (null == suffix)
    return false;
  else if (double.TryParse(value.Substring(0, value.Length - suffix.Length), 
                           out double number)) {
    try {
      result = s_Builders[suffix](number);

      return true;
    }
    catch (OverflowException) {
      return false;
    }
    catch (ArgumentException) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Finally, `MyParse` is very simple:

```
public static TimeSpan MyParse(string value) =>
  TryMyParse(value, out var result)
    ? result
    : throw new FormatException($"{value} is not a valid time");
```

**Demo:**

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "17.24s",
    "20.79m", 
    "1.3h",
  };

  string demo = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,6} :: {Math.Round(MyParse(test).TotalSeconds),4}"));

  Console.Write(demo);
```

**Outcome:**

```
  17.24s ::   17
  20.79m :: 1247
    1.3h :: 4680
```

Comment: I'd first parse the string into the number and the suffix then use the suffix to lookup the translation method in the dictionary rather than iterating over the dictionary.  Note that `suffix` will never be `null` since all strings end with `""`.

Comment: @juharr: I check for `null` to be on the safe side: if `{ "", ...` is commented out in the model, we can well have `null` suffix. It's not that easy task (in general case) to split the string into number and suffix, e.g "1.23e-2y2e4" with `1.23e-2` number and `y2e4` suffix; I admit the example is academic one, but I want to be on the safe side

Comment: I'd just check if the last character is a number since we only expect one character suffixes.  If not that's the suffix.  If it is a number there is no suffix and you try to parse the entire string as a double.  Now if we need to handle suffixes of varying lengths then what you have would make more sense.

Comment: You're rigth.   20.79 minutes == 20.79 * 60 seconds == 1247 seconds
    1.3 hours   == 1.3 * 3600 seconds == 4680 seconds

Answer (score 0):

`Timespan` does have a `Parse` method that accepts a string parameter but it uses a different input format than what you want. See more information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parse?view=netcore-3.1

You'll have to make your own parse method to convert a string input to a `Timespan` and use the `TotalSeconds` property to get the number of seconds.

If you go this route I would suggest starting by writing a unittest first containing all the inputs considered valid and their expected result. From there you can implement your parse method and verify it.

```
namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Tests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void TestTimespanStringConversion()
        {
            // Test cases go here...
            Assert.Equal(TimeSpan.FromHours(1.2), "1.20h".AsTimeSpan())
        }
    }

    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static TimeSpan AsTimeSpan(this string input)
        {
            // Conversion logic goes here...
            return new TimeSpan();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you'd want to compare `"1.2h.AsTimeSpan()` to `TimeSpan.FromHours(1.2)`

Comment: Yeah expected goes first I recall now, so it should be `Assert.Equal(TimeSpan.FromHours(1.2), "1.20h".AsTimeSpan())`. Edited answer